# Cakephp 3, table association error (one to one relationship)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this tables: | Users | Clients | (one to one relationship)

I need to create a User first, and after create the Client, with the "user last inserted id". Here is how I tried:

## Client Controller

```
public function add()
{
    $userId = null;
    $client = $this->Clients->newEntity();
    $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $this->request->data);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Clients->User->newEntity();
        $user->role_id = 2; // client
        $user->username = $this->request->data['cnpj'];
        $user->password = $this->request->data['cnpj'];

        if ($this->Client->User->save($user)) {
            $userId = $this->Client->User->getLastInsertId();
        }
    }
    if (isset($userId) && $this->request->is('post')) {
        $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity ( $client, $this->request->data );
        $client->user_id = $userId;
        if ($this->Clients->save ($client)) {
            $this->Flash->success ('The client has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect (['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error ( 'The client could not be saved. Please, try again.' );
        }
    }

    $regions = $this->getRegions();

    $this->set(compact('client', 'regions'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['client']);
}
```

--

## ClientsTable

```
class ClientsTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
 public function initialize(array $config)
 {
     $this->table('clients');
     $this->displayField('id');
     $this->primaryKey('id');
     $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
     //$this->belongsTo('Users', [
     $this->hasOne('Users', [
         'foreignKey' => 'users_id'
     ]);
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better follow the conventions instead of trying to fumble together your own solution. Once properly associated, all you need to do is pass the request data in the correctly formatted fashion according to your associations, and CakePHP will take care of the rest, that is including inserting the proper foreign key values before saving associated data.

In case of a `hasOne` association, the data would need to look something like

```
[
    'username' => '...',
    'password' => '...',
    'client' => [
        'some_client_column' => '...'
    ]
]
```

Please check the docs on how to save data for further details:

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasone-associations**